# Cómo saber si existe un dato dentro de un arreglo y mostrar un mensaje en pantalla indicando que existe?, Lenguaje Java!

Tags: java

**Cómo saber si existe un dato dentro de un arreglo y mostrar un mensaje en pantalla indicando que existe?, Lenguaje Java!**

import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

```
public static int main(String[] args) {
    
        int n;
        Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Asigne un tamaño al arreglo: ");
        n=leer.nextInt();

        int[] arr=new int[n];
        
        for(int x=0;x<arr.length;x++){
            arr[x]=(int) (Math.random()*20)+1;
        }

        int bus;
        System.out.print("Digite el dato que desea buscar: ");
        bus=leer.nextInt();
        

}
```

}

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema _específico_ que has tenido? Lee [ask].

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

**Espero que te sirva, saludos!!**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n;
    boolean encontrado = false;
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Asigne un tamaño al arreglo: ");
    n = leer.nextInt();

    int[] arr = new int[n];

    for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        arr[x] = (int) (Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    }
    // Mostrar el arreglo para que veas los numeros que hay dentro 
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }

    int bus;
    System.out.print("\nDigite el dato que desea buscar: ");
    bus = leer.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == bus) {
            encontrado = true;
        }
    }
    if (encontrado == true) {
        System.out.println("El dato introducido esta dentro del array.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("El dato introducido no esta dentro del array.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [answer]. [es.so] no es un repositorio de código; responde a preguntas en donde el autor de la misma haya indicado qué problema ha tenido. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Gracias bro, me salvaste!